# C program Strings Example how come the result is 98?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

C program Strings Example how come the result is 98?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main() 
 {
  char s[]="%d%d%d";
   int a=9,b=8,c=5;
     printf(s+2,a,b,c);
    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Think about the resulting string if you do `s + 2` (it's the same as doing `&s[2]` by the way). Then think about what would happen if you put that as a format string in `printf`.

Comment: What do you think `printf("%d%d", 9, 8, 5)` prints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string + x` is an operation called [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).
That way you are providing reference to a mathematically calculated memory area and by semantics it is equivalent to `&string[x]`
What actually happens behind the calculation:
`(&string + (x * sizeof(*string)))` which is why it is a very specific notion when it is applied to pointers. That stands for Arrays as well as they decay to a pointer to the first element after all.

---

As for your code, you have the following string:

```
char s[]="%d%d%d";
```

And is passed as the format string for printf, two bytes afterwards, which explicitly provides reference to `"%d%d"`

---

Therefore this:

```
printf(s+2,a,b,c);
```

Is later parsed as:

```
printf("%d%d",a,b,c);
```

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) will except two integers to read from and the 3rd one will be simply - ignored.

Comment: That answer is more technical and more majority-user friendly. And more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Expression `s+2` speaking in images moves pointer s (in expressions array designators are converted to pointers to their first elements) two positions to the right. So the format string in the printf statement will look like

```
"%d%d"
```

because expressiom `s+2`points to the third character of string `"%d%d%d"`
As result statement

```
printf(s+2,a,b,c);
```

will output only two first arguments a and b because the pointed substring contains only two format specifiers and you will get

```
98
```

If for example you would use expression `s + 4` in the `printf` call you would get only

```
9
```

Comment: @haccks What do you mean?

Comment: @haccks I usually have a problem to find correct English words for my thoughts.:)

Comment: Then you are not alone :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for the response ! i got it now .